# Modify the “kmeans” function to include the condition that all cluster centers have a value from a given raster

Tags: r, spatial-cluster

I would like, if possible, to add a condition to the “kmeans” function. The condition is that all centers of final clusters must have values from a given raster, and thus, should not contain any NAs.

Here is the modified function, but I’m unsure if my solution is correct. The code that I added is displayed as ###.

```
kmeans_mod <- function (x, centers, raster, iter.max = 10L, nstart = 1L, algorithm = c("Hartigan-Wong", "Lloyd", "Forgy", "MacQueen"), trace = FALSE){
  
  .Mimax <- .Machine$integer.max
  
  do_one <- function(nmeth){
    switch(nmeth, {
      isteps.Qtran <- as.integer(min(.Mimax, 50 * m))
      iTran <- c(isteps.Qtran, integer(k))
      Z <- .Fortran(C_kmns, x, m, p, centers = centers, 
                    as.integer(k), c1 = integer(m), c2 = integer(m), 
                    nc = integer(k), double(k), double(k), ncp = integer(k), 
                    D = double(m), iTran = iTran, live = integer(k), 
                    iter = iter.max, wss = double(k), ifault = as.integer(trace))
      
      switch(Z$ifault, stop("empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers", call. = FALSE), 
             Z$iter <- max(Z$iter, iter.max + 1L), stop("number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)", call. = FALSE), 
             warning(gettextf("Quick-TRANSfer stage steps exceeded maximum (= %d)", isteps.Qtran), call. = FALSE))
    }, {
      Z <- .C(C_kmeans_Lloyd, x, m, p, centers = centers, 
              k, c1 = integer(m), iter = iter.max, nc = integer(k), 
              wss = double(k))
    }, {
      Z <- .C(C_kmeans_MacQueen, x, m, p, centers = as.double(centers), 
              k, c1 = integer(m), iter = iter.max, nc = integer(k), 
              wss = double(k))
    })
    
    if(m23 <- any(nmeth == c(2L, 3L))){
      if(any(Z$nc == 0)){ 
        warning("empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers", call. = FALSE)
      }
    }
    if(Z$iter > iter.max){
      warning(sprintf(ngettext(iter.max, "did not converge in %d iteration", "did not converge in %d iterations"), iter.max), call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
      if(m23){ 
        Z$ifault <- 2L
      }
    }
    if(nmeth %in% c(2L, 3L)){
      if(any(Z$nc == 0)){ 
        warning("empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers", call. = FALSE)
      }
    }
    Z
  }
  
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  m <- as.integer(nrow(x))
  
  ############################
  if(length(centers) != 1L){
    stop("The argument centers must be an integer")
  }
  ############################
  
  if(is.na(m)){
    stop("invalid nrow(x)")
  }
  
  p <- as.integer(ncol(x))
  
  
  if(is.na(p)){
    stop("invalid ncol(x)")
  }
  
  if(missing(centers)){
    stop("'centers' must be a number or a matrix")
  }
  
  nmeth <- switch(match.arg(algorithm), `Hartigan-Wong` = 1L, Lloyd = 2L, Forgy = 2L, MacQueen = 3L)
  
  storage.mode(x) <- "double"
  
  k <- centers
  
  ############################
  ## Initialize the data frame "centers_within_layer"
  centers_within_layer <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = dim(x)[2]))
  ############################
  
  ############################
  ## Run the loop while there are not k centers
  while(dim(centers_within_layer)[1] != k){
  ############################
    
    if(nstart == 1L){
      centers <- x[sample.int(m, k), , drop = FALSE]
    }
    
    if(nstart >= 2L || any(duplicated(centers))){
      
      cn <- unique(x)
      mm <- nrow(cn)
      
      if(mm < k){
        stop("more cluster centers than distinct data points.")
      }
      
      centers <- cn[sample.int(mm, k), , drop = FALSE]
    }
    
    k <- as.integer(k)
    
    if(is.na(k)){
      stop(gettextf("invalid value of %s", "'k'"), domain = NA)
    }
    
    if(k == 1L){
      nmeth <- 3L
    }
    
    iter.max <- as.integer(iter.max)
    
    if(is.na(iter.max) || iter.max < 1L){
      stop("'iter.max' must be positive")
    }
    
    if(ncol(x) != ncol(centers)){
      stop("must have same number of columns in 'x' and 'centers'")
    }
    
    storage.mode(centers) <- "double"
    Z <- do_one(nmeth)
    best <- sum(Z$wss)
    
    if(nstart >= 2L && !is.null(cn)){
      
      for(i in 2:nstart){
        centers <- cn[sample.int(mm, k), , drop = FALSE]
        ZZ <- do_one(nmeth)
        
        if((z <- sum(ZZ$wss)) < best){
          Z <- ZZ
          best <- z
        }
      }
    }
    
    centers <- matrix(Z$centers, k)
    dimnames(centers) <- list(1L:k, dimnames(x)[[2L]])
    cluster <- Z$c1
    
    if(!is.null(rn <- rownames(x))){
      names(cluster) <- rn
    }
    
    totss <- sum(scale(x, scale = FALSE)^2)
    
    ############################
    ## Check if the centers of clusters have values from the raster
    centers_within_layer <- na.omit(terra::extract(raster, data.frame(centers[, 1:2]), xy = TRUE))
    ############################
    
  }
  
  structure(list(cluster = cluster, centers = centers, totss = totss, withinss = Z$wss, tot.withinss = best, betweenss = totss - best, 
                 size = Z$nc, iter = Z$iter, ifault = Z$ifault), class = "kmeans")
}
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to test the code due to the following error message:

> Error in do_one(nmeth) : object 'C_kmns' not found

I have attempted to create a reproducible example:

```
library(terra)
    a <- terra::rast(ncols=400, nrows=400, xmin=-110, xmax=-90, ymin=40, ymax=60, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
    values(a) <- runif(ncell(a), 1, 100)
    a[a > 60] <- NA
    ## plot(a)
    df_a <- terra::as.data.frame(a, xy = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
    test_kmeans <- stats::kmeans(df_a, centers = 100) ## replace with the modified function
    test <- na.omit(terra::extract(a, data.frame(test_kmeans$centers[, 1:2]), xy = TRUE))
    dim(test)[1] == 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is because your new function isn't in the same "environment" or "namespace" as the original, so any objects defined in the old functions environment won't be found.

I can replicate your error with:

```
> Z <- .Fortran(C_kmns)
Error: object 'C_kmns' not found
```

Where's the `kmeans` function's environment?

```
> environment(kmeans)
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

and here's the object we want:

```
> environment(kmeans)$C_kmns
$name
[1] "kmns"
[etc]
```

We can also get that as a non-exported object from the `stats` namespace:

```
> Z <- .Fortran(stats:::C_kmns)
Error in .Fortran(stats:::C_kmns) : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (0), expecting 17 for 'kmns'
```

The error here is because I've not bothered to add all the other arguments, The chances are any more "Not found" errors will be related to this sort of issue and solvable by adding `stats:::` (or `stats::`) to the name...